# Angular-translate, translate content from database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, angular-translate

I'm using AngularJS and angular-translate for the internationalization. However my site has products loaded from the database. Since I want to avoid making 3 different collections and loading one based on language, I want to use one and translate the content dynamically.

So far I've tried the straightforward way, by entering the following in my database:

```
"name" : "{{'product_general' | translate}}",
```

However it just renders it as a string on my site. Is there a possible solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing just the placeholder in the database. The part in the single quotes in your example:

> product_general

Once you read it from the database, put that reference in the view and it should work.

In the controller:

```
$scope.valueReadFromDb = ...;
```

In the view:

```
{{ valueReadFromDb | translate }}
```

Alternatively, if you want to translate something in the controller side instead of the view, for whatever reason, you can inject $filter in your controller and do something like this:

```
var translate = $filter('translate');

$scope.someVariable = translate('PLACEHOLDER');
```

Comment: That might work, but creating scope variables for ~1000 products might be too much. Is there a way I can nest those things since I'm using ng-repeat, something like:
        {{ {{filter._id}} | translate}}